# Is instance variable shared between super class and sub class in java

Tags: java

```
class A{
 String foo="bar";
 void m(){

 }
}

class B extends A{
//String foo="xyz";
void m(){
    foo="xyz";
    System.out.println(foo);
    System.out.println(super.foo);
}
}

public class Dell{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    A a=new B();
    System.out.println(a.foo);
    a.m();

}
}
```

Here is foo variable shared between super class (A) and sub class (B).When I called super.foo in m() method why doesnt it called A class foo variable value that is bar.It seems that foo is shared between both the classes.Bu how is this possible? When we declare A with foo variable then it has its own copy and now when we overirde it and changed foo value in child class then how it is reflected back in Super class? Kindly explain we concepts in well way

Comment: Because there is only one `foo` field for class `B`.

Comment: then what about foo field in class A?

Comment: foo will be inherited or not?

Comment: If foo is not marked as private, then it will be inherited by the subclass.

Comment: `foo` is **inherited**; and you already have a way to *shadow* `foo` commented out in your code (`//String foo="xyz";`).

Comment: @MayankSingh `foo` is already being inherited

Comment: Take a real example! Dad has an age property of age=40 and its son also has age property ie age =20 but how changing age in son can change dad's age

Comment: @MayankSingh Is the **son** *also* the **dad**? ***Or***, are there *two* `People`?

Comment: but both has different age and how changing in one can reflect others age.Age propert is inherited from Dad to son but how changing from one can reflect to another

Comment: instance variable are shared between sub class and super class but how it is possible?

Comment: @MayankSingh If the age was inherited by the child, then the child would be the same age as the parent. Your question makes no sense, think of another example.

Comment: @MayankSingh: If a superclass already defines a property, why would the subclass need to define it as well?  What you're asking doesn't really make sense, and your "dad/son" example definitely doesn't make sense because those are two instances of the same thing, not an inheritance structure.

Comment: as conclusion tell me that instance variable are shared or inherited?

Comment: When you create your B class above. It has inherited the value of bar which was initialized in the superclass. But in your m method, then it assigns a new value to the variable foo of "xyz". It doesn't matter whether you output foo or super.foo thereafter. It's the same value, as you've written to it. It's only one variable. You don't access multiple versions of the variable for various subclasses like you do for methods.

Comment: @MayankSingh `static` are shared , instance members are inherited unless both are `private`

Comment: @MayankSingh: All instance members are inherited.  Members marked `private` aren't accessible (though they still exist).  Members can be shadowed or in some way overridden, though it's not clear if that's what you're trying to do here.  It's really not clear what you're asking or why.

Comment: If you override the variable foo in your subclass, then that's another matter of course, but you've commented it out above. Try it and see for yourself. http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what you need to understand about instance variable scope within super and subclasses.

http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15